# I'd like the browser to display data from "2015 to 2015" in white

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

'''python'''
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import

```
ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import  time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.pakwheels.com/")
print(driver.title)


year_of_model=driver.find_element(By.ID,"home-query")

year_of_model.send_keys("2015")
search_button=driver.find_element(By.ID,"home-search-btn")
search_button.click()

colour = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="collapse_16"]/div/ul/li[1]//a/input')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", colour)
try:
    From_year = driver.find_element(By.ID, "yr_from")
    To_year = driver.find_element(By.ID, "yr_to")
    From_year.send_keys("2015")
    To_year.send_keys("2015")
    go = driver.find_element(By.ID, "yr-go").click()
except ElementNotInteractableException as e:
    print(f"The Error is:{e} ")
time.sleep(30)
```

I think something is missing

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import  time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.pakwheels.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
print(driver.title)

#//*[@class="btn btn-sm btn-link-outline btn-classified"]
# year_of_model=driver.find_element(By.ID,"home-query").send_keys("2015")
#
# search_button=driver.find_element(By.ID,"home-search-btn")
# search_button.click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@class="btn btn-sm btn-link-outline btn-classified"]').click()


try:


    From_year = driver.find_element(By.ID, "yr_from")

    To_year = driver.find_element(By.ID, "yr_to")
    From_year.send_keys("2015")
    To_year.send_keys("2015")
    Go_ = driver.find_element(By.ID, "yr-go")
    Go_.click()
    time.sleep(3)

    colour = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="collapse_16"]/div/ul/li[1]/label/a/input')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", colour)
    time.sleep(5)



except ElementNotInteractableException as e:
    print(f"The Error is:{e} ")

time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).